# Showing welcome text is wrong when switch websites - related to Session

Tags: customer-session, multi-website, magento2.4.1

***Enviroment***:

- Magento version 2.4.1
- PHP 7.4
- MariaDB 10.0.26

***Setting***:

- The website has multiple websites (2 websites)
- Login into Dashboard -> setting Account Sharing Options is **Per websites**

[image]

***Reproduce bug:*** 
First, login website A. We can see welcome text in the header. "*Welcome, Trang Thi*"
[image]

After that, I switch to website B. Immediately, you will see the unreasonably here.
I have installed not sharing an account between websites, but some functionality of the old account still appears. Example: My account, Company Structure, ...

[image]

I think this error is related to the session, please help me and give me a solution to resolve it. 
Thank everyone for reading!

Comment: up up up up up up

Comment: :(( up up up up up part2